# How to mark katalon test execution in zephyr through script?

Tags: ui-automation, katalon-studio, jira-zephyr

I have some test cases written in Katalon. I need to execute them from Katalon and mark directly to Zephyr in already created test cycle. Please provide any step-by-step guide to implement this Katalon-Zephyr integration.

Comment: I think you have solution  <https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-integration-with-zephyr-for-jira/8176/11>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Katalon for a while (using Cypress now) but I answered the same in the Katalon forum. You need to use the API from the Zephyr Apiary:
https://getzephyr.docs.apiary.io/#reference/executionresource/update-execution-details/update-execution-details

**Steps below:**

1. Create a web service request under Object repository (let’s call it
   ZAPI- Update Execution Details) using ZAPI API:
   **http://test123.atlassian.net/rest/zapi/latest/execution/15/execute**
2. Include the code below inside @AfterTestCase under the Test
   Listeners:

.

```
String statusID = '' 
if(testCaseContext.getTestCaseStatus().equalsIgnoreCase('PASSED')){
 statusID = '1' //1 is the code for PASSED in Zephy
}else{ //default to Failed
 statusID = '2' //2 is the code for FAILED in Zephyr
}
def update_test_execution_status = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('ZAPI-Update Execution Details', [('exId') : '15', ('exStatus') : statusID]))
```

**Note:** For now, I only included the following status: PASSED and FAILED; Test execution ID is different from Issue Type ID.